# concurrent non-malleable *statistical* zero knowledge

Tags: cr.crypto-security, zero-knowledge

According to Huijia Lin and
Rafael Pass's "[Concurrent Non-Malleable Zero Knowledge with
Adaptive Inputs](http://people.csail.mit.edu/huijia/papers/AdapCNMZK.pdf#page=3)" paper:

> if collision-resistant hash functions exist, then
>   "there exists a $\omega\left(\log^2(k)\right)$-round concurrent non-malleable zero-knowledge proof with adaptive input selection (and a with a black-box simulator) for all of NP",

where the "adaptive input selection" is in the strongest strongest sense that I know of.

As far as I can tell, their assumptions can be reduced to 2-round
statistically hiding commitment with publicly verifiable opening.
However, after searching online, 
I do not see any results for concurrent non-malleable *statistical* zero knowledge.

> Is there any known construction for
>   *concurrent non-malleable statistical zero-knowledge arguments of knowledge*
>   (in the plain model)?